# Kotlin retrofit Multipart problem with send file on server(server work on laravel)

Tags: android, laravel, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit2

i have a problem with sending files over using retrofit to my API server. When i send data over using the @Body anotation but without a file the data gets added. When i use @multipart i keep getting response.code()==401, with me using postman sending data with files through my API it works perfectly fine. The issue lies within the kotlin app and retrofit.

i used every possible way. I used multipart without file, same problem.  i tried sending just the file and it was the same thing. I don't have a clue where the problem is or what it could be. using body allows me to send data over while with @multipart it looks like as if they just didn't want to transfer over. any recommendations on what to do would be very much appreciated.

myCode:

```
interface FarmSpaceApi {
    @POST("auth/register")
    fun RegisterUserApi(@Body user: User):Call<User>
    @POST("auth/login")
    fun LoginUserApi(@Body user: Userlogin):Call<LoginData>
    //@POST("fields/create")
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    @POST("fields/show")
    fun getFields(@Body userId: UserId,@Header("Authorization")token:String):Call<Field2>

    @Multipart
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    @POST("fields/create")

    fun addfield(@Header("Authorization") token:String,
                 @Part image:MultipartBody.Part,
                 @Part("fieldstype") fieldstype: RequestBody,
                 @Part("field_size_in_ha") field_size_in_ha: RequestBody,
                 @Part("harvest_in_this_year") harvest_in_this_year: RequestBody,
                 @Part("user_id") user_id: RequestBody):Call<FieldNewResponse>

}
```

```
clicker.setOnClickListener {
    val tokenManager=TokenManager(this)
    val filepath=tokenManager.getfilename()
    val file= File(filepath)
    Log.d("File ", file.name.toString())
    Log.d("fieldname ",fieldname.toString())
    Log.d("fieldsize ",fieldsize.toString())
    Log.d("fieldcurrent ",fieldcurrentyear.toString())
    val request=RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"),file)
    val filepart=MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file",file.name,request)
    viewModel.sendfield(
        tokenManager.getTokenfromManager()
        ,filepart
        ,fieldname.toString()
        ,fieldsize.toString().toDouble()
        ,fieldcurrentyear.toString().toDouble()
        ,tokenManager.getidentyficator()!!.toInt())

}
```

```
@Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
   override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 100) {
           imageuri = data?.data!!
           Log.d("Uri", imageuri.toString())
           imagepreview.setImageURI(imageuri)
           val name: String = getNameFile(this, imageuri)
           Log.d("name: ", name)
           val tokenManager=TokenManager(this)
           tokenManager.addfilename(name)
       }
   }

fun getNameFile(context: Context, uri: Uri): String {
       val projection: Array<String> = (arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA))
       val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null)
       val index: Int = cursor!!.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
       cursor.moveToFirst()
       val name: String = cursor.getString(index)
       return name
           //.substring(name.lastIndexOf("/")+1)

   }
```

```
fun sendfield(token:String,filepart:MultipartBody.Part,name:String,size:Double,year:Double,id:Int) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        Log.d("token ", token)
        val retro = InstanceApi.getInstanceApiRetrofit().create(FarmSpaceApi::class.java)
        val newname= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),name)
        val newsize= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),size.toString())
        val newyear= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),year.toString())
        val newid= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),id.toString())


        retro.addfield("Bearer " + token,filepart,newname,newsize,newyear,newid).enqueue(object : Callback<FieldNewResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<FieldNewResponse>, response: Response<FieldNewResponse>) {
                Log.d("Git ", response.message().toString())
                Log.d("Test ", response.body().toString())
                Log.d("Testcode ", response.code().toString())
                Log.d("Testerror ", response.errorBody().toString())
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<FieldNewResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("Nie Git ", t.message.toString())
            }

        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please mention that whether your API is in PUT or POST mode of multipart??, It will help better to narrow down issue

Comment: My api is in post mode. I send data to my api and server response me status with message. When i want only save data on my serwer with api i post data with @Body and server save this data on server. When i want response data from my server it is too correct. I only use POST metod in my api and multipart. We can see in first code @POST("fields/create")

Answer (score 0):

Response code `401` means unauthorized.
The `Bearer <token>` parameter must be set in request's header, not in the body.

Comment: I removed what broke the impression that you are attempting to answer. If you cannot answer without asking a question first please find something else to answer. In case I have deleted a purely rhetoric question feel free to add an assertive (i.e. non-asking) phrasing of it.